Postgresql on Linux Mint 21.3 can not create server
I downloaded the desktop version of postgresql on my linux mint 21.3 successfully (over Ubuntu Jammy Download-Method) but it still seems to have a problem with the connection.
postgresql connection problem
I tried to use this solution: Stackoverflow Solution for this problem
but sadly it didn't work. I also couldn't see the port which my postgresql is working on.
Can someone provide me a solution?

(1) Have you followed this installation method, (2) If PostgreSQL is not listening on any port then it's not running.

tbh, just did it by myself. That could be the problem xD @harrymc I'll try with the instruction.
